# How can I call Sling Filter before AuthenticationHandler?

Tags: aem, sling

I want to put a sling filter before the authentication handler, but I have no luck.

From the logs I can see that the authandler always called after my filter. Is there a good documentation about this? Is it possible to put a filter before the authenticationhandler?

Both works when I put logging to the authandler's extractCredentials method and to the doFilter method of Filter. But unfortunately my Filter is called after the authandler.

Here is my logs:

```
11:50:55.924 AuthenticationHandler extractCredentials
11:50:56.004 Before chain.doFilter
11:50:56.332 After chain.doFilter
```

Comment: You can't do this, as in my answer. Consider posting a second question where you describe *why* do you want to do this and what high-level result you'd like to achieve - maybe it isn't neccessary to create such filter at all?

Answer (score 2):

Authentication is always done before the filter processing:

> - Request level
>
>   - Authentication
>   - Resource Resolution
>   - Servlet/Script Resolution
>   - Request Level Filter Processing

(source: [Sling documentation](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html#filter-processing)).

So, you can't create a filter that would be run before the authentication.

Comment: I found an ugly solution, if I use pattern, then my filter won't be a sling filter, but it will run before sling filter chains. http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-http-service.html#filter-service-properties

Comment: [aem-acs-sample](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/blob/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/filters/impl/legacy/SampleServletFilter.java) works in AEM 6.1 but in AEM 6.2 the sling engine is coming before filter. @nerd did you test your change in AEM 6.2 or 6.3?

Comment: @SandeepKumar I haven't worked with AEM since 2015. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OSGI Preprocessor, it will act as a filter before authentication is called, you will find the specification and one example here:
https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.http.whiteboard.html#service.http.whiteboard.servlet.preprocessors